GitHub Actions Workflow Fails to Finish Due to nohup Command in EC2 Deployment
This is my GitHub Actions workflow for deploying code to an EC2 instance. The problem is that the nohup command never terminates, so the SSH connection and the workflow itself do not finish. I’ve monitored the EC2 server and confirmed that the Go build file is created and executed correctly. How can I resolve this issue? Any help would be appreciated!
name: EC2 auto deploy

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Deploy
        run: |
          echo "${{ secrets.PRIVATE_KEY }}" > private_key
          chmod 600 private_key
          
          ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no \
            ${{ secrets.USER_NAME }}@${{ secrets.HOST_NAME }} \
            -i private_key \
            "cd /home/ec2-user/my-app && \
            git switch main && \
            git fetch origin && \
            git pull origin main && \
            /usr/local/go/bin/go build -o main cmd/server/main.go && \
            lsof -ti:8080 | xargs --no-run-if-empty kill && \
            nohup ./main >> /home/ec2-user/output.txt 2>&1 < /dev/null & \
            sleep 5"
          
          echo "Deployment completed"


As you rightly mentioned, the issue you’re encountering is due to the nature of the nohup command, as it continues running in the background and doesn’t terminate the SSH session, which is what’s causing your GitHub Actions workflow to hang.
One suggestion that comes to mind is to modify the SSH command to disconnect properly after running the background process. You can disassociate the nohup command from the current shell session by using the disown command.
So you can modify the nohup command in your workflow like this :
nohup ./main >> /home/ec2-user/output.txt 2>&1 < /dev/null & disown && \

The disown command should fully detach the process from the SSH session, allowing the SSH connection to close properly without having to wait for the background process to finish.
Give this a go and let me know if this works for your use case.

Thank you for your advice! However, unfortunately, it didn’t resolve the issue.
I tried the command you suggested, but the situation remains unchanged.
The GitHub workflow exited with the following message:
client_loop: send disconnect: Broken pipe
Error: Process completed with exit code 255.

